# image not displaying

Tags: c#

I hope you can help me!  I am trying to make a game similiar to candyland.  I want the die to spin when the user clicks the button.  A random number is chosen and based on that number, the dice displays the image for that number.  That works!  Then, I want our user to be able to move forward on our board- based on the spot that they're on, it adds whatever they spinned and the image on that spot  becomes visible.  When in debug mode, everything works perfectly but for some reason, the pawn never moves!  Can you please tell me why.  I am attaching my code below.  Thank you so much!

```
protected void btnSpin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        int x = randomNumber.Next(1, 6);
        switch (x)
        {
            case 1:
                //imgDie.ImageUrl = "~/Images/dice1.jpg";
                Session["Die"] = "~/Images/dice1.jpg";
                break;
            case 2:
                Session["Die"] = "~/Images/dice2.jpg";
                break;
            case 3:
                Session["Die"] = "~/Images/dice3.jpg";
                break;
            case 4:
                Session["Die"] = "~/Images/dice4.jpg";
                break;
            case 5:
                Session["Die"] = "~/Images/dice5.jpg";
                break;
            case 6:
                Session["Die"] = "~/Images/dice6.jpg";
                break;
        }
        imgDie.ImageUrl = (string)Session["Die"];

        place = place + x;
        switch (place)
        {
            case 2:
                img2.Visible = true;
                img2.ImageUrl = (string)Session["Imagesrc"];

                break;
            case 3:
                img3.Visible = true;
                img3.ImageUrl = (string)Session["Imagesrc"];
                break;
            case 4:
                img4.Visible = true;
                img4.ImageUrl = (string)Session["Imagesrc"];

                break;
            case 5:
                img5.Visible = true;
                img5.ImageUrl = (string)Session["Imagesrc"];

                break;
            case 6:
                img6.Visible = true;
                img6.ImageUrl = (string)Session["Imagesrc"];

                break;
            case 7:
                img7.Visible = true;
                img7.ImageUrl = (string)Session["Imagesrc"];

                break;
            case 8:
                img8.ImageUrl = (string)Session["Imagesrc"];
                img8.Visible = true;
                break;
```

Comment: what is Session["Imagesrc"] ?

Comment: what framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

my guess is your 'place' variable is a member field and it's being reinitialized with each page construction. chnge your place variable to be viewstate or session state like your other stuff.